# Masks animation in the graph view is possible?

Tags: animation, masking

I have an animated mask. Can I modify easings of it in the "Graph View"?
There is some sort of "Mask" mode like one in the "Dope Sheet"?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to access the mask information on dopesheet or curve editors.

Comment: @cegaton, dope sheet has "mask mode" with mask`s keyframes. I using it to ajust, delete and copy/paste repetitive states. But seems like graph-view have no this feature.