# Can't set keyframe type of mask

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, keyframes, shape-keys, dopesheet

Switching type does nothing at all. Keyframes stay normal yellow keyframes with unneeded linear motion between. Even if automatic keyframe insertion set to extreme or breakdown.

How do I hold mask keyframe to get rid of mask motion between keyframes?

[image]

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Blender 2.79b

Comment: Set the interpolation to constant.

Comment: @cegaton this also does nothing as for me. Did you tried it? It seems like _any_ motion options not working for 'mask' keyframes, including motion graphs. Is it? I tried it with different version of blender and get the same result. May be I doing something wrong and there special mode for mask motion settings? But i don't know about it.

Comment: Okay, I found there a question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19248/masks-animation-in-the-graph-view-is-possible
It really looks like blender does not have any 'mask' keyframe motion settings, even option to disable default linear motion. This is very sad.